# How to open window of Autostart Application for all devices?

Tags: android, autostart

How to open window of Autostart Application for all devices?

Comment: you can use adb comment to boot your application but mbl should be rooted.

Comment: what is a `window of auto start application`?

Comment: Please, can you edit your question and perform it with more info?

Answer (score 18):

Below site will give you idea about **Autostart**

https://www.androidauthority.com/auto-start-app-review-61346/

Below Codes will help you to open the settings to enable the **Autostart** for most of the Phones.(Collected from many sources)

Special Thanks to [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642478/xan/) and https://github.com/dirkam/backgroundable-android

```
private static final Intent[] AUTO_START_INTENTS = {
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.lool",
      "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity")),
    new Intent("miui.intent.action.OP_AUTO_START").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")).setData(
      Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart"))
  };
```

and inside your OnCreate()

```
for (Intent intent : AUTO_START_INTENTS){
      if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
   }
  }
```

or

Better to show it like the code below to make user understand why to enable it.

```
 for (Intent intent : AUTO_START_INTENTS)
      if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this).title("Enable AutoStart")
          .content(
            "Please allow App to always run in the background,else our services can't be accessed when you are in distress")
          .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
          .positiveText("ALLOW")
          .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
              try {
                for (Intent intent : AUTO_START_INTENTS)
                  if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          })
          .show();
        break;
      }
```

eg:

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.savingyou.android.R;


public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final Intent[] AUTO_START_INTENTS = {
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.lool",
      "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity")),
    new Intent("miui.intent.action.OP_AUTO_START").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
    new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")).setData(
      Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart"))
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (Intent intent : AUTO_START_INTENTS){
      if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
      }
   }
  }
}
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @ Sachin Varma

Comment: can samsung smart phones needed autostart permission?

Comment: Yes needed for some Samsung Unmonitored Apps (7.0+)

Comment: I created an app with foreground service. I installed the app in a vivo device but it does not show up on the list of autostart apps inside settings. How do I make my app appear in the list?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones, Autostart is needed only for Background services.

Comment: @SachinVarma then how come my foreground service still gets stop?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario how it gets killed? Foreground services will only stop, when you stops it programatically, or your app gets killed due to some RAM or memory issues.

Comment: how to check if app is already whitelisted

Comment: As of now and as per my knowledge, there is no way to detect it.

Comment: Thanks..It's worked perfectly.. @Sachin Varma

Comment: any possibility we can check USER has already added app into  appstart or by default option

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml below code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" 
android:name="yourpackage.BootReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then create a new class BootReceiver.java

```
public class yourActivityRunOnStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe helpful for you. Good luck!